# Injecting Redirect JS in Chrome extension. Fail! :(

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to generate an extension that keeps my brother of facebook. So I decided i'll redirect all facebook links to google for starters.

This is how i went about it.

My manifest.json file :

```
{   

  "name": "FBRehab"    
  "version": "1.0",    
  "description": "Redirect FB",    
  "permissions": [    
   "tabs", "http://www.facebook.com/*", "https://www.facebook.com/*"    
],     
  "browser_action": {    
   "default_icon": "icon.png",    
"background_page": "background.html"    
      },
  ]
}
```

My background.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "try.js" });
});
</script>
</head>
```

and try.js

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var time = null
function move() {
window.location = 'www.google.com'
}
</script>
</head>
```

Yet, it does not redirect. I've tried directly injecting the try.js using content scripts too.

Please help me.

Thanking you.

Ashar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember a [Background Page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) runs exactly once in Chrome, it is a single long running script that runs exactly once.

Basically what your code does now is that once your browser loads, it will inject jquery and try [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to the current tab. You have no tabs that are currently loaded (which it will fail unless you have it auto load a tab). Then it will not do anything anymore because the Background Page runs exactly once!

What you need to do instead is use a [Content Script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) which should be defined as follows:

```
// Only execute in the top window, we don't want to inject the iframes.
if (window == top) {
  window.location = 'www.google.com'
}
```

In your manifest, you will have the following:

```
{
  "name": "No more Facebook extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["redirect.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: @AsharRaiMujeeb Now your brother is going to learn how to access and disable extensions :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a [**content script**](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) instead of a background page. You can specify that your content script should only run on specific web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever call move()? Doesn't look like it to me, but I've never developed a Chrome extension before... so I'm not sure if it is ever called automatically.